# Babel not including relevant polyfills for IE 11

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm attempting to transpile a website with the following `babel.config.js` file:

```
const addExports = require('babel-plugin-add-module-exports')
const babelEnv = require('@babel/preset-env')
const flow = require('@babel/preset-flow')
const react = require('@babel/preset-react')
const istanbul = require('babel-plugin-istanbul')
const lodash = require('babel-plugin-lodash')
const reactRequire = require('babel-plugin-react-require').default
const classProperties = require('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties')
const exportFrom = require('@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from')
const reactDisplayName = require('@babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name')
const browsers = '> 1%'

module.exports = function (env, instrument) {
  const plugins = [
    addExports,
    classProperties,
    exportFrom,
    lodash,
    reactDisplayName,
    reactRequire
  ]

  if (instrument) { plugins.push(istanbul) }

  return {
    plugins,
    presets: [
      [
        babelEnv,
        {
          loose: false,
          targets: { browsers },
          useBuiltIns: 'usage',
          corejs: 2
        }
      ],
      flow,
      react
    ]
  }
}
```

Although it appears that IE 11 is included in the '> 1%' browsers query, there was still an error observed upon loading the page in IE 11:

`Object doesn't support property or method 'sinh'`.

The offending line of code is basically:

`Math.sinh(...)`

And it does look like [IE 11 does not support the `sinh` method of `Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sinh). Once I included the code `import 'es6-math'` at the very beginning of my root js file, the code is able to run on IE 11.

But my question is, why didn't the babel transformation include this polyfill automagically? Am I missing some kind of configuration?

Comment: It could just be a pattern I've never seen, but I don't think you have to require the actual plugin/preset packages to use them (at least when using a ```.babelrc``` file), just list the package names as strings in the plugin/preset array.  I also recommend ```core-js``` or ```@babel/polyfill``` for IE support, it bundles all of the polyfills in one place.

Comment: Is it not enough for me to be specifying core-js 2 in the `@babel/preset-env` configuration?

Comment: What version of `@babel/preset-env` are you using?

Comment: Additionally, is it possible the `Math.sinh` call isn't used in your entry file (or tree)?  Babel won't include polyfills for methods it doesn't find while transpiling.

Comment: I'm using @babel/preset-env v7.5.5. The `Math.sinh` is included in a node_module that the project requires, however, theoretically the method that actually uses `Math.sinh` would never be called.